# Python-Accessing values of dictionary using lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given dict:

```
dict=[ {'Confirmed_cases' : {'Brazil' : 1600,'Indonesia' : 2400}, 
        'Death_cases': {'Brazil' :30, 'Indonesia' : 68}]
```

how can I get `1600` values from `confirmed_cases` using `lambda`? based on `user input = Brazil`

Comment: Using lambda? How about just using the keys? `d[0]['Confirmed_cases']['Brazil']`

Comment: 1. Do not use python 'reserved words' as name for variables 2. in you example dict  is a list which as a dict as its only element.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
data = [{'Confirmed_cases' : {'Brazil' : 1600,'Indonesia' : 2400}, 'Death_cases': {'Brazil' :30, 'Indonesia' : 68}}]
confirmed_cases = lambda x: data[0]['Confirmed_cases'][x]
print(confirmed_cases('Brazil')) # > 1600
```

Not sure if its a good practice to name your dictionaries `dict` though. I would imaging its a reserved name.

Hope I could help! :)

Comment: aww thank's, it works! but i have a little bit change because i got some error(keyerror) on data[0],then i deleted the [0]. so the final fix is: lambda x: data['Confirmed_cases'][x].

Answer (score 0):

If you want lambda this may look weird but works:

```
list_dict=[{'Confirmed_cases' : {'Brazil' : 1600,'Indonesia' : 2400}, 'Death_cases': {'Brazil' :30, 'Indonesia' : 68}}]

def get_value(list_dict, key, country):
    return list_dict.get(list(filter(lambda x: x == key,list_dict))[0]).get(country)

x = get_value(list_dict[0], 'Confirmed_cases', 'Brazil')
```

You can replace the hardcoded strings with userinput.